# Functions of random variables $Y=3X^{4}$

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand the following concept, and in particular , here is an example.

I am wanting to find the density function of the random variable $Y=3x^{4}$ (strictly increasing on this interval)

given that the random variable $X$ has density function

$f(x)=\frac{1}{8}(1+x)$ for $2 \lt x \lt 4$ , and $0$ anywhere else

My thoughts:

I thought that to do this, we were to write

I note $$F_{x}(X)= \frac{1}{8}(x+\frac{x^2}{2})$$

$$f_{y}=f_{x}|\frac{dx}{dy}|$$

But I don't know in what terms to keep things, for example, should I write this as

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{12x^3}$$

Or do I have to at some point switch variables, ie write $$(y/3)^{\frac{1}{4}}=x$$

and write $$dx=\frac{1}{12}(y/3)^{\frac{-3}{4}}dy$$

for example?

or do i need $$F_{x}({\frac{y}{3}})^{1/4}$$
Ie, I am just confused on how to put this all together and make sense of it.

Thanks for any help, I am really wanting to understand what I am doing here. If someone could work this problem out for me I think I could follow along and truly understand it. As of now I have a bunch of different ideas, but nothing coherent

Comment: Because students often have trouble with the method of transformations, I prefer to find the cdf of $Y$ and then differentiate. For suitable $y$, we have $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(3X^4\le y)=\Pr(X\le (y/3)^{1/4})=\int_2^{(y/3)^{1/4}}\frac{1}{8}(1+x)\,dx$.

Comment: Ah, so I just use $F_{X}(x)$ and plug in as such, and this is equivalent to method of transformation?

Comment: It is more work than the method of transformations. Note that we can differentiate under the integral sign, so for the density we don't really need to integrate. I mentioned the method mainly because often the logic of this version is clearer to students. But transformations, in the one-to-one case, is quicker.

Comment: So if it is not one to one, then can I always use the way you explained it as using the integrals and such?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ "lives" say on the interval $(-1,1)$ and for example $Y=X^2$, the method of transformations gets tricky, while the cdf method works reasonably smoothly, though one has to be careful about the inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is over an interval that is one-to-one, what you want to do is
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(\sqrt[4]{y/3})}{\left|\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{\sqrt[4]{y/3}}\right|} = f_X\left(\sqrt[4]{y/3}\right)\left|\left.\frac{dx}{dy}\right|_{\sqrt[4]{y/3}}\right|.$$
It looks strange, but I wrote it like that for completeness.
In other words, yes you should be plugging in $x = \sqrt[4]{y/3}$ since your density should be in terms of $y$, not $x$.

So,

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(\sqrt[4]{y/3})}{\left|\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{\sqrt[4]{y/3}}\right|} = \frac{\frac{1}{8}\left(1+\sqrt[4]{y/3}\right)}{\left|12\,\sqrt[3/4]{y/3}\right|}.$$

Comment: Thanks but why would I divide by absolute value of derivative instead of multiply? And do I actually evaluate its value there? Could you possibly elaborate on the post if you have the time?

Comment: They are equivalent. I will edit my post.

Comment: So what would the final form be then?

Comment: Done. You could also do it the cdf way, but I'd prefer not to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I will be going over it tomorrow and seeing if anyone else has any input then I will accept an answer,

Comment: Sure, no problem. The great/awful thing about probability is that there are usually many ways to do each problem. It can be overwhelming.